# Cumulative result of items for drawing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table ENG_Drawing.Its fields are

```
SELECT DrawingID,DrawingNumber,DrawingDescription FROM ENG_Drawing 

DrawingID        DrawingNumber      DrawingDescription   etc..
1131            R152-14-01-00-31       DU - 01              etc..    
....
1200            R160-02-01-00-21       DU - 12              etc..        
....
.....
....
1500            R156-01-01-00-11       DU - 00              etc..
....
.....
2993        R167-09-01-00-21       DU - 04              etc..
2994        R165-10-01-00-40       DU - 25              etc..
2995        R163-13-01-00-01       DU - 24              etc..
2996        R100-12-01-00-61       DU - 21              etc..
2997        R166-09-01-00-21       DU - 21              etc..
2998        R125-14-01-00-02       DU - 32              etc..
2999
3000
 .
 .
```

And detail table for drawing table is

```
DrawingID   SeqNbr  Drawing_f   BOMQuantity    ItemQty        DrawingreferenceID   ItemID
1131        7       0           2               0.574                           1231
1131        9       1           4               null        1200                null
....        
....
1200        14      1           8               0.560       1100                1555
1200        16      1           2               5.23        1500                1755
....
....
1500        18      0           2               4.350                           2684
....
2993        5       0           2               0.061                           2125
2993        6       0           2               1.592                           1698
2993        7       0           2               2.500                           1231
2993        9       1           4               null        1131                null
2993        16      1           2               null        1500                null
2993        18      0           2               4.350                           2684
```

When I give DrawingID as 2993
In need output like this

```
ITEMID  TOTALQTY
1231    9.592  //select((2*2.500) + (4*2*.574)) here (2*2.500)- is BOMQuantity(4)*ItemQty(2.500) for ItemID 2993 and (4*2*.574)- BOMQuantity of DrawingID 1131(4)*BOMQuantity of ItemID 1231 in DRawingID 1131(2)*ItemQty(.574)
1555    71.680  //select(4*4*8*.560) here 4-BOMQuantity of DrawingreferenceID 1131 in DrawingID 2993.Middle 4 is BOMQuantity of DrawingreferenceID 1200 in DrawingID 1131. 8 is  BOMQuantity of ItemId 1555 in DrawingId 1200
1698    3.184  //select(2*1.592)
1755    50.944  //select(4*4*2*1.592)
2125    0.122  //select(2*0.061)
2684    0.122  //select((2*4.350)+(2*2*4.350))
```

ENG_Drawing_BOM contains subdrawings (DrawingreferenceID).they(DrawingreferenceID) have their values in ENG_Drawing table and also have items and subdrawings.
One drawing may have no of subdrawings and that subdrawings can have subdrawings and so on....

I need When i give DrawingID i need Item wise  cumulation.The result should be is ITEMID,sum( BOMQuantity * ItemQty) as TOTALQTY.
The problem is,
For exmple
 DrawingID has subdrawing with 4 BOMQuantity, i need TOTALQTY 4 times of that subdrawing(S1) items, 
 if that subdrawing has subdrawings(S2) with 6  BOMQuantity need 4 times of S1 items and 4*6 4 times of S2 items ...It will continue for its inner levels...

I finally need Overall ITEMID wise cumulation

here 2993 as main drawing.1131,1200,1500 are subdrawings and that subdrawings may have sub drawings.I need them also .

Any body????

Comment: i think you have ask 2-3 question at one go .I am getting confuse.see ENG_Drawing has nothing to with your requirement.i think you can just join to include drawingnumber,description etc.First give proper example of heirarchy

Comment: @KumarHarsh , I have edited my query.Here DrawingId in Eng_Drawing is PK.Details for each drawing is in ENG_Drawing_BOM table.

Comment: Sorry @Suresh "The result should be is ITEMID,sum( ... onward is not clear .why don't you show expected output ?say i pass 2993 then wht should be the output look like.

Comment: @KumarHarsh , Hi I give sample output values.Can u help me.

Answer (score 1):

@Suresh recheck your sample data,what is wrong in my query ?

```
Declare @drawing table( DrawingID int,SeqNbr int,Drawing_f int,BOMQuantity decimal(5,2),ItemQty decimal(6,3),DrawingreferenceID int,ItemID int)
insert into @drawing
select 1131 ,       7,       0,2, 0.574,null,1231 union all
select 1131 ,       9,       1,4,null ,1200,null union all
select 1200,        14,      1,8,0.560,       1100,1555 union all
select 1200,        16,      1,2,5.23 ,       1500,1755 union all
select 1500,        18,      0,2,4.350,       null,2684 union all
select 2993,        5,       0,2,0.061,         null,2125 union all
select 2993,        6,       0,2,1.592,          null,1698 union all
select 2993,        7,       0,2,2.500,         null,1231 union all
select 2993,        9,       1,4,null ,       1131,null union all
select 2993,        16,      1,2,null ,       1500,null union all
select 2993,        18,      0 ,2,4.350,         null,2684 
--select  * from @drawing 
;with cte as
(select  * ,1 roots from @drawing where DrawingID=2993 
union all
select d.*,case when d.DrawingID=c.DrawingreferenceID then roots+1 else roots end from @drawing d inner join cte c on d.DrawingID=c.DrawingreferenceID 


)
select   * from cte
```

@Suresh if your last query is ok then make it accurate

```
with cte as
(
    select  d.* , 1 as Nooff,1 roots,d.DrawingID as 'MainDrawing' from ENG_Drawing_BOM  d 
    union all
    select d.*,c.BOMQuantity*C.Nooff  as Nooff,case when d.DrawingID=c.DrawingreferenceID then roots+1 else roots end ,MainDrawing as 'MainDrawing' 
    from ENG_Drawing_BOM d inner join cte c on d.DrawingID=c.DrawingreferenceID 
)
,CTE1 as
(
select 
    cte.MainDrawing,
    cte.ItemID, 

    SUM(Nooff*cte.UnitWeight)as 'Wt',
    SUM((TotalQty)*Nooff)  as 'TotalQty'
from cte

where DrawingReferenceID is   null AND MainDrawing = 2993
group by cte.ItemID, cte.MainDrawing


)
select 
    cte.MainDrawing,
    cte.ItemID, 
    i.ItemDescription,
     Wt,
    TotalQty
from cte1
    inner join STR_Item i on cte.ItemID = i.ItemID 
where DrawingReferenceID is   null AND MainDrawing = 2993

    ORDER BY cte.ItemID
```

Comment: Thanks!!! @KumarHarsh.From your reply I have got my need.i have added my exact  need.Is there any easiest way.please help me.Before your post I have achieved this task using subquery with UNION ALL.Now I have adopted to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is exact need ...derived from KumarHarsh reply.

```
with cte as
(
    select  d.* , 1 as Nooff,1 roots,d.DrawingID as 'MainDrawing' from ENG_Drawing_BOM  d 
    union all
    select d.*,c.BOMQuantity*C.Nooff  as Nooff,case when d.DrawingID=c.DrawingreferenceID then roots+1 else roots end ,MainDrawing as 'MainDrawing' from ENG_Drawing_BOM d inner join cte c on d.DrawingID=c.DrawingreferenceID 
)



select 
    cte.MainDrawing,
    cte.ItemID, 
    i.ItemDescription,
    SUM(Nooff*cte.UnitWeight)as 'Wt',
    SUM((TotalQty)*Nooff)  as 'TotalQty'
from cte
    inner join STR_Item i on cte.ItemID = i.ItemID 
where DrawingReferenceID is   null AND MainDrawing = 2993
group by cte.ItemID,
    cte.MainDrawing,
    i.ItemDescription
    ORDER BY cte.ItemID
```